# Add a new data field and automatically populate it in Google Form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have following data to be collected:

Name | address | pn

now what i want is when the data is submitted there must be a new field json_data.

For eg:
When name="hello", address="address", pn="000",
the auto field json_data should be:

```
{
"name":"hello",
"address":"address",
"pn":"000"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is you will have to create responses spreadsheet from your from by clicking the green rectangle with the cross in it. Submit at least one response and build your formula in the next cell on that line.  I built

```
="}
    'name' : "&D2&",
    'address' : "&E2&",
    'pin' : "&F2&",
    }"'
  }'
```

using Ctl-enter to get the new lines. Search using 'new line in formulas' for why '\n' does not work.  Perfect your result in the spreadsheet.

Copy your formula into your script and use cell.setFormula.

Your script can copy the formula to the end of the data range as needed (daily, weekly) with a trigger but I don't know how you could automatically add it as a new response is added. The least complicated way would be to just add the formula before the spreadsheet is used by whatever process comes next.